# How to set up a VPN in a different subnet

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, subnet, windows-server

Let's suppose we have the following configuration:

[image]

When I setup my VPN role in the Windows Server to allocate IPs to VPN clients from the range 192.168.1.10 to 192.168.1.20 everything works fine.

However, when I want to isolate the VPN clients in a different subnet (for example 192.168.2.0/24) then I don't know how to proceed. The connection to the VPN server works fine, my VPN client gets the address 192.168.2.2 for example, and is able to ping the server at 192.168.1.2, but can't see the other machines in 192.168.1.0/24 and can't reach the Internet though.

I know that I have to add some static route somewhere, but I don't really see where. Any pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your internet router doesn't know anything about the 192.168.2.0 network, and so neither does any of the other hosts, as their router is the internet router.

Add a route to the internet router, saying that 192.168.2.0/24 is at 192.168.1.2.  You might also need to adjust the NAT on the router so that it NATs this network as well. Some do this automatically.

Now if a VPN user wants to talk to 192.168.1.4 the outgoing packet will go to the Windows server, then straight to 192.168.1.4.  1.4 does not have a route for 192.168.2.x so will send the response to its default gateway  - 192.168.1.1.  This has a route to the Windows box for 192.168.2.x so the reply will go to the Windows server, and then to the VPN user.

There is a possibility the router won't "hairpin route" - ie, it won't route a packet back out of the interface it came in on.

If that is the case, then you'll need to add a manual route to each device in 192.168.1.x saying that 192.168.2.x is via the Windows server.

Comment: This is working perfectly fine now!
Since I'm experimenting with multiple configurations in order to learn, I have another question: what if I want now to "isolate" the subnets, I mean that 192.168.2.0/24 VPN clients can still be able to access the Internet through 192.168.1.1 but can't see any other 192.168.1.0/24 machine. How this would be done using this same configuration?

Comment: As they all traverse the Windows Server, the simplest approach would be to set firewall rules on the server that deny access to the 192.168.1.0 network.